# Python convert 2 columns to JSON like with extra quotes

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
ACCT#    Type     FirstName     last5
1234    primary     John        99999  
45689   secondary    Max        14569
```

I need a dataframe like this: last column in JSON but not realy.It's enclosed in double quotes, and every key/value is also enclosed in addition double quotes

```
ACCT#    Type           datahooks
1234    primary   "[{""last5"": ""99999"",""firstName"": ""John""}]"  
45689   secondary  "[{""last5"": ""14569"",""firstName"": ""Max""}]"
```

Comment: Just to be sure, `"[{""last5"": ""99999"",""firstName"": ""John""}]" ` is semantically same as `"[{"` `"last5"...` and not "enclosed in additional quotes" as you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: Why do you want it like that? What can parse that?

Comment: Why not just store it as real JSON?

Comment: its how the file we need to process at our end application.